# Graphviz Composite Structure Diagram

Tags: graph, uml, graphviz, dot

Is it possible to generate with Graphviz / dot a UML composite structure diagram like the one below?

[image]

Comment: I think plantuml (http://plantuml.com/) can draw such an image, and the engine used by plantuml is dot.

Comment: No plantuml cannot do this.

Comment: The closed one that i found is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157650/moving-graphviz-edge-out-of-the-way

Comment: Without the ports it would not be a problem. With the ports, or elements on the border in general, I suspect that it is not possible.

Comment: But why using dort? When you just need an open source solution to draw an uml diagram, why not using eclipse with emf and a uml viewer?

Comment: @Matthias I was thinking of the http://plantuml.com/component-diagram but what you draw looks more like a hardware diagram, with exact port mappings. plantuml can output LaTeX (Tikz) so that might be a basis for further investigations for you.

Answer (score 0):

By using (open) box arrowheads https://graphviz.gitlab.io/doc/info/arrows.html, this gets pretty close:

```
digraph boxed {
graph [splines=ortho nodesep =.75]
node [shape=box]
edge [dir=both arrowtail=obox arrowhead=obox]
{ rank=same
    x1 -> x2 -> x3
}
x1:s -> y1:n
}
```

[image]